# UWP TimePicker MVVM

Tags: mvvm, uwp-xaml

I am having problems getting the Time property of the TimePicker into my ViewModel.The method on the ViewModel

```
TimePickerTimeSelected()
```

is called but BEFORE the Time property is updated.

```
private DateTimeOffset _datePickerValue;
public DateTimeOffset datePickerValue
 {
     get => _datePickerValue;
     set => SetProperty(ref _datePickerValue, value);
 }
```

Here isthe XAML

```
<TimePicker
     Name="timePicker"
     Time="{x:Bind viewModel.timePickerValue,Mode=TwoWay}"
     TimeChanged="{x:Bind viewModel.TimePickerTimeSelected,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

I want to do some processing with the time when it is selected in the control but the method is called before the timePickerValue is updated.How do I get the new time? ViewModel method:

```
  public void TimePickerTimeSelected()
  {

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Xaml you are setting `Mode=TwoWay` to `TimeChanged` Event which is invalid, as `TmeChange` is an Event and not a `DependencyProperty`.

In order to achieve the desired output please refer to the below code:

Xaml:

```
<TimePicker
   Name="timePicker"
   Time="{x:Bind ViewModel.TimePickerValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
   TimeChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestTimeChangedEvent}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
  private TimeSpan _timePickerValue;
  public TimeSpan TimePickerValue
  {
     get { return _timePickerValue; }
     set { _timePickerValue = value;}
  }

  public void TestTimeChangedEvent(object sender, TimePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     TimePickerValue = e.NewTime;
  }
```

**EDIT**

As you don't want to use TimePickerValueChangedEventArgs in your ViewModel, you have to create a custom behavior to get the selected time in your VM.

XAML:

```
 <TimePicker
     Name="timePicker">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <behaviors:TimeChangedEventBehavior/>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
 </TimePicker>
```

Behavior:

```
  public sealed class TimeChangedEventBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
    {
        public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

        public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
        {
            if (!(associatedObject is TimePicker tp))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Error Associating Object");
            }

            this.AssociatedObject = associatedObject;

            tp.TimeChanged += OnTimeChanged;
        }

        private void OnTimeChanged(object sender, TimePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var timePicker = (sender as TimePicker);
            var mainVM = (timePicker.DataContext as MainViewModel);
            mainVM.OnTimePickerTimeSelected(timePicker.Time);
        }

        public void Detach()
        {
            if (this.AssociatedObject is TimePicker tp)
            {
                tp.TimeChanged -= this.OnTimeChanged;
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
 public void OnTimePickerTimeSelected(TimeSpan selectedTime)
 {
     // Your Logic       
 }
```

Comment: Yes thanks that does indeed work but your taking a dependency on the UI with the TimePickerVaueChanged which I was hoping to avoid. Is there a way to use MVVM ? You would normally set the property in the viewmodel and that's how you get the value. There would be no reason to have the timePickerVaue otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer.Awesome Sir!